# Is $[A,\exp{B}]=0 \Rightarrow [A,B]=0$ true?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematics

The backward direction is trivial and this one probably too, but I just can't find a convincing argument.

$A$, $B$ are Operators on a Hilbert Space (Ket Space).

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Maybe, but as physicists deal a lot with such commutators I asked here. Should I move the thread?

Comment: General tip: Never crosspost, but you might flag for migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true. Take for example
$$ B = 2\pi \mathrm{i} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} , $$
then $\exp(B) = 1$ and $[A,\exp(B)] = 0$ for all $A$.

However, clearly, $[A,B] \neq 0$ for some $A$.

Comment: This seems legit. Do you know where the mistake might be in my proof-scetch?

Comment: You sure that exp(B)=1 ? I tried calculating exp(B) using Mathematica, and I'm getting exp(B) = {{1,1},{1,1}}, and not the value of {{1,0},{0,1}} (= Identity matrix).

Comment: Let $B=2\pi i S$. Then $S^2=1$ and so $e^{2\pi i S}=\cos(2\pi)+i \sin(2\pi) S=1$.

Comment: @SamuelWeir I also calculated it using Mathematica ;) remember to use MatrixExp and not Exp (which is elementwise exponentiation).

Answer (score 0):

One may argue that
$$
[ A,\exp(tB)] = 0 \\ \Rightarrow 0 = \partial_{t} [ A,\exp(tB)]\\ \Rightarrow 0 = \partial_{t|t=0} [ A,\exp(tB)]= [A,B\exp(tB)]_{t=0} = [A,B]
$$
.

However, as Noiralef pointed out, one may not conclude
$$
[ A,\exp(B)] = 0 \Rightarrow [ A,\exp(tB)] = 0
$$

Comment: From $[A, \exp(B)] = 0$ you can not conclude that $[A, \exp(tB)] = 0$ for all $t$

Comment: Ok, aggreed. I'll edit my answer and let it stand here. Maybe others can learn from it as well.